# Google Login integration Error: 401. Error: deleted_client The OAuth client was deleted. What is the solution here?

Tags: api, google-oauth, google-signin

I wanted to integrate Google Login with my website. I have created an oauth client with proper Authorized JavaScript origins and Redirect URIs. I have also enabled APIs and used client ID and Secret Key. I have been shown the following error many times:

```
401. That’s an error.

Error: deleted_client

The OAuth client was deleted.
```

Request Details are as follows:

```
redirect_uri=storagerelay://https/www.#mysite.com?id=auth357681
response_type=permission id_token
scope=email profile openid
openid.realm=
client_id=#myclientid
ss_domain=https://www.#mysite.com
fetch_basic_profile=true
gsiwebsdk=2
```

"#value is hidden here."

What could be the issue?
I have tried creating it many times but same error has been opening up.
P.S. I have also tried many other solutions for similar questions but no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolve like same issue please check your google-signin-client_id, recreate google-signin-client_id and change the value of meta google-signin-client_id

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="12345678-gbgin9h7q69rpjehq1cd2441b4nosnid.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

For more information https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: Yes, it was static. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much.. I was getting depressed with all these google errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using firebase, deleting and recreating the Google provider under sign-in methods also works, google will auto-generate it for you.